# Symbolic link modification for HP unix

Tags: find, symbolic-link, hp-ux

I'm trying to modify the following in order to rename some symbolic links:

```
find /home/user/public_html/qa/ -type l \
  -lname '/home/user/public_html/dev/*' -printf \
  'ln -nsf $(readlink %p|sed s/dev/qa/) $(echo %p|sed s/dev/qa/)\n'\
 > script.sh
```

Unfortunately the `-lname` option does not work for HPUX. Do you know something equivalent that I can use?

Just to give you and idea of my problem, I want to change all the symbolic links inside a particular folder.

```
New Symbolic link --> /base/testusr/scripts 
Old Symbolic link --> /base/produsr/scripts
```

Now folder "A" contains more than 100 different files having soft links which I need to change in this manner.

Comment: Addressing a question to a particular user doesn't work.

Comment: thanks for editing Dennis, as the script I was referring to was from David so mentioned his name.

Comment: hi All, my issue got resolved with the following solution         "find . -type l -exec ll -a {} + | awk '{ print "ln -sf", $11, $9}' > script"

Answer (score 1):

With only POSIX tools, the only way to see the target of a symbolic link is through `ls`. The Linux and BSD `readlink` command is unfortunately not standard.

Using `ls` is brittle because you have to parse out the file names. Assuming that your file names do not contain newlines and that the targets of the symlinks do not contain the substring `->`, the command `ls -l "$link" | sed 's/.* -> //'` prints the target of the link.

```
find /home/user/public_html/qa/ -type l |
while IFS= read -r link; do
  target=$(ls -l "$link" | sed 's/.* -> //')
  case $target in
    /home/user/public_html/dev/*)
      link_to_change=$(echo "$link" | sed s/dev/qa/)
      ln -nsf "$(echo "$target" | sed s/dev/qa/)" "$link_to_change";;
  esac
done
```